# GMS2 - Why am I getting this syntax error?

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I made an inventory system(other is the drop) and here is the pickup code

```
    // pickup

    found_in_inv = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < ds_list_size(global.inv); i++){
        if(global.inv[| i][| 0] == other.object_index){ // error line
            global.inv[| i][| 1]++;
            found_in_inv = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found_in_inv){
        instance_destroy(other);
    }else{
        for(var i = 0; i < ds_list_size(global.inv); i++){
            if(global.inv[| i][| 0] == noone){
                global.inv[| i][| 0] = other.object_index;
                global.inv[| i][| 1] = 1;
                break;
                instance_destroy(other);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting a syntax error where "[|" found, ")" expected. I don't know how to fix this, please help.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the lines with `global.inv[| i]` (the `[|`) by `[`?
(Eg: `global.inv[i]`) that seems the syntax error to me.

Comment: Then it just says that it got “[“ not “)”

Comment: I'm not sure if using `|` inside any of the array brackets is valid gml, perhaps that's causing the syntax error, could you remove all of them, and if not, could you mind explaining why you're using that?

Comment: The new gml uses [| index] for ds_lists now and the problem is the if statement

Answer (score 2):

Chained accessors (a[i][k], or a[|i][|k] in your case) are only supported in version >= 2.3 (as of writing this, [is in beta](https://www.yoyogames.com/blog/565/gamemaker-studio-2-version-2-3-beta-release)).

Assign the first retrieved item into a variable to get around the fact.
Perhaps also take an opportunity to not do more reads than you need.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < ds_list_size(global.inv); i++){
        var item = global.inv[| i];
        if(item[| 0] == other.object_index){ // error line
            item[| 1]++;
            found_in_inv = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```